# How do I align/snap different objects together?

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine, units, blenderkit

I'm still a beginner and I'm trying to design the Toyota AE86 from Initial D.

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to align vertices together so they look as one. For example, I have the hood & the front bumper, and they look a bit off. I want the hoods side to align with the front bumpers side vertically.

[image]

I'm sure it has something to do with snapping objects together because I also have the same issue around here:

[image]

How could I solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: you can select both the 2 objects, go in Edit mode, and snap the vertices. But the best is probably to use the topology of one object (for example the edge of the bumper) in the other one?